# How to set batch file output to be the same as the bat file directory

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, batch, batch-file

I've created a `.bat` file that I can use to drag and drop an mp4 video file onto it to convert reddit videos format to a format supported by whatsapp. All this using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)
Here's the code of the `.bat` file:

```
"D:\Programas\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%~1" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac ./out.mp4
PAUSE
```

As you can see, pretty straightforward.
My only issue resides on the `./out.mp4` part of the command, where if I drag and drop from say "Downloads", and the `.bat`file is sitting on the `Desktop`, the `out.mp4` file will be created on `Downloads` instead of `Desktop`.

How can I alter this behavior (besides setting the output to `/path/to/Desktop/out.mp4`), so I can move the bat file elsewhere and still get the same intended behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after RTFM https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html
Section called:  *Links relative to the Batch Script*

You can use `%0` for the "batch file path"
So, the solution for this particular case would be:

```
"D:\Programas\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%~1" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac "%~dp0/out.mp4"
PAUSE
```

Comment: Oh well, feel free to edit the answer then!

Comment: Yes, consistently on diferent directories and also across different hard drives. I Don't know if it works across network locations, as I don't have any.

Comment: to be consequent and safe, quote the output file too: `"%~dp0/out.mp4"` (there might be spaces or other poison chars in `%~dp0`)

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense, edited.